# How to show labels inside a chart with R-plot?

Tags: r, plot

I have the following chart in R:

```
n = 1:50
f = log2(n)
g = n
h = n*log2(n)
k = n^2
z = 2^n
w = factorial(n)
plot(n, f, ylim=c(0,200), t='l', col=3)
lines(n, g, t='l', col=2)
lines(n, h, t='l', col=3)
lines(n, k, t='l', col=4)
lines(n, z, t='l', col=5)
lines(n, w, t='l', col=6)
```

[image]

Is there a way to show the names/labels of each of the functions similar to the following figure:

[image]

Comment: try [`text`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/text.html): `plot(1:5, 1:5);text(2, 3, "foo")`

Comment: Hello @bouncyball, thank you very much! It worked and solved my problem!

Comment: @bouncyball The only problem with text is to represent the 2 to the n or the n to the square, is there any way to do this using the text function?

Comment: To plot math symbols and formulas see `help('plotmath')`.